# Enabling graphics acceleration for OpenGL over remotely via VPN from Ubuntu client(my laptop)to Windows server(computation is here)

Tags: hardware, vpn, graphics, remote-desktop, opengl

I have an access to Internet via a Wifi.

Then, I have a VPN connection established from my Ubuntu laptop to a LAN network. My Windows Machine where computation happens using OpenGL is on the same network.

After establishing the VPN connection from my Ubuntu Laptop to the LAN network, I used rdesktop (and other remote desktop clients like KRDC) to run the program on the Windows machine. It fails, because of rdesktop or others not supporting certain graphics hardware acceleration via remote desktop, being transferred from the Windows Machine back to my Ubuntu Laptop for remote client on Ubuntu to see/visualize. Errors like "Shaders not supported...":

[image]

How can I solve this, please ?

After Googling, I arrived at the possibilities ..

Should I use team viewer ?

It had earlier worked comfortably from a MAC OS laptop to the Windows Machine. Is it a good idea to set up MAC OS virtually on my Ubuntu laptop and then establish VPN and remote desktop via virtual MAC ?

Can VirtualGL help ?

Answer (score 3):

TurboVNC is specifically developed for remote use of graphics acceleration. It is used at several Academic and Government "high-performance computing" organizations for exactly this purpose.

I would suggest you look into it and similar products, rather than a commercial solution that is not designed with specific requirements for remote graphics acceleration.

TurboVNC website:
http://www.virtualgl.org/

Comment: I stand by my statement. Team Viewer is a commercial application. Just because they allow one to use it without cost for personal use does not make it free, in the sense of free software. It is free in the sense that you don't pay out of pocket, but you get what they give you.

Answer (score 1):

NoMachine is my personal favourite (when it does not play up) for a number of reasons:

- Hardware acceleration of compression (video of desktop).
- Works on Windows and Linux.
- Works well on low-bandwidth connections especially if the client and server have the necessary hardware for compression of the data stream.
- On Linux you get your desktop as you last left it when you were sitting in front of the machine.
- On Windows and Linux it does not affect OpenGL.
- It is free to use as long as you do the installation and its only used within your company. IANAL so do double check with your licence compliance officer.

Answer (score 0):

Teamviewer Works !!

It is free for personal use right now, and the visualizations are supported !